# Can I access the information of an error in a continue handler?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure, I can have a continue handler that handles errors. Can I somehow access the details of the respective error inside the handler?

Small example:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `DO_SOMETHING_WRONG`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `DO_SOMETHING_WRONG`()
BEGIN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Hey, this is an error!';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

(That's obviously the failing part of the example)

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `CALL_SOMETHING_WRONG`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `CALL_SOMETHING_WRONG`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE ERROR_OCCURRED BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET ERROR_OCCURRED := TRUE;
    
    CALL DO_SOMETHING_WRONG();

    IF ERROR_OCCURRED IS TRUE THEN
        SELECT 'An error occurred!' AS Output;
    ELSE
        SELECT 'No error occurred!' AS Output;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I call `CALL CALL_SOMETHING_WRONG();` it gives me *An error occurred!* as it should, but can I let it tell me, what error? So, get hold of the `45000` and the `Hey, this is an error!` in this example?

Comment: Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/get-diagnostics.html

Comment: @BillKarwin For me, the official MySQL documentation is extremely hard to read and understand.